# Multiple Select to insert 1 colum with 1 result

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    C.CompanyId, 
    CompanyName, 
    Server, 
    ServerUsers, 
    ServerUptime, 
    ServerHostName, 
    ServerType 
FROM 
    CUSTOMERS AS C
INNER JOIN 
    USERS ON C.CompanyId = USERS.CompanyId
WHERE 
    USERS.UserEmail='matt' AND 
    USERS.UserPin='5153' AND 
    (SELECT Status FROM 4321_BlackBerryServices LIMIT 0,1)
LIMIT 0, 8
```

Currently my table is below

```
        4321    T1 Solutions    EXCH-01 392 47 days, 17 min exch01.myCorp.com   ExchangeServices
        4321    T1 Solutions    EXCH-02 685 47 days, 17 min exch02.myCorp.com   ExchangeServices
        4321    T1 Solutions    Lync-01 368 47 days, 17 min lync01.myCorp.com   LyncServices
        4321    T1 Solutions    Lync-02 890 458 days, 58 min    lync02.myCorp.com   LyncServices
```

What i would like to do is add the last result from Status FROM 4321_BlackBerryServices  so i would want to add the latest status for each server in my table

how is this possible ?

Comment: Can you post your table schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you need, try this:

```
SELECT 
    C.CompanyId, CompanyName, Server, ServerUsers, 
    ServerUptime, ServerHostName, ServerType, 
    (SELECT Status FROM 4321_BlackBerryServices 
     ORDER BY field_you_know DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS BBS_Status
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
INNER JOIN USERS 
    ON C.CompanyId = USERS.CompanyId
   AND USERS.UserEmail = 'matt' 
   AND USERS.UserPin = '5153'
LIMIT 0, 8
```

In my query `field_you_know` field is the one you know you can sort the table to take the last one.